# What is the use of "tank experience" once you've maxed the tank?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Once you max a tank (elite status) you gain more "free experience" (gold stars) available for every other tank upgrade, but you still receive standard tank experience (silver stars).

What is the use for that? Can they be spent or changed into something?

I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: You can pay to make it free experience that can be added to anything.

Comment: @kotekzot please do not remove such crucial tags..

Comment: @christian.s platform tags should only be applied when a problem is unique to that platform.

Comment: @kotekzot it is here - i just deleted my answer as it does not apply for the xbox-360 version, but for the pc. i could not know the author asked for xbox-360 because you removed the tag..

Answer (score 2):

You can use gold coins to convert tank specific exp into free exp.

You can also check the box that says "Accelerate crew training" (in the garage view), which doubles the XP gained by the crew member with the lowest experience, this consumes all of the tank specific exp. Free exp is not affected by this.

Comment: Where is the box to check? I've never seen it

Comment: it's above the list of crew members, I've only played PC version so I'm not sure about the xbox version.

Comment: You sure it exists on the console version?

Comment: i'm not sure, but if it doesn't, that's quite a big thing missing.

Comment: crew training does not exist on the 360 version yet, IIRC.